# How do I create a dropdown menu in kineticjs

Tags: javascript, web, drawing, html5-canvas, kineticjs

I am trying to create a diagram editor using Kineticjs.

Currently, I want to create a drop down menu with a scrollbar as in a select box.  However, I am not sure of how to do that in Kineticjs.  Can someone give some advice as to the logic of the implementation of drop down menu in Kineticjs?

An [example](https://www.google.co.jp/search?safe=active&hl=en&site=imghp&tbm=isch&source=hp&biw=1301&bih=682&q=select+box&oq=select+box&gs_l=img.3..0l10.2361.3876.0.4129.10.10.0.0.0.0.240.1132.6j3j1.10.0.crnk_timediscountc..0.0...1.1.17.img.KhzPt57gERE#facrc=_&imgdii=_&imgrc=EApulgmxQGY2SM%3A%3BKHgyD2qm9e6EPM%3Bhttp%253A%252F%252Fmanual.qooxdoo.org%252F1.4%252F_images%252Fselectbox.png%3Bhttp%253A%252F%252Fmanual.qooxdoo.org%252F1.4%252Fpages%252Fwidget%252Fselectbox.html%3B650%3B259) of what I want to create

Thank you very much in advance.

Warmest Regards,
Dandy Ling

Comment: What do you want your drop down menu to do, or what is it for? Will it be like a select box? This question is very vague, we need some more information on what you are trying to do.

Comment: As great as KineticJS is, you should probably stick with DOM when creating form controls for accessibility reasons.  Most KineticJS apps use KineticJS for grahics and DOM elements for form controls, text, and dialogs.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could just use the `Layer` and `Group` collections to logically create your Dropdown Box.

Adding the "mouseover/mouseout" events, you could just show/hide the groups within the Layer.

Then to make it really nice, you could use the Tween/Animation classes to animate the x/y position of each of the options.

Then you just need to hook-up the "click/touchdown" events to methods that call you core logic.